# What versions of spaCy suport en_vectors_web_lg?

Tags: python, spacy

I am trying to download en_vectors_web_lg, but keep getting the below error:

```
ERROR: Could not install requirement en-vectors-web-lg==3.0.0 from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_vectors_web_lg-3.0.0/en_vectors_web_lg-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl#egg=en_vectors_web_lg==3.0.0 because of HTTP error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_vectors_web_lg-3.0.0/en_vectors_web_lg-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl for URL https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_vectors_web_lg-3.0.0/en_vectors_web_lg-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl#egg=en_vectors_web_lg==3.0.0
```

Is spacy still supporting en_vectors_web_lg?

I also just updated my spacy to the latest version

Comment: @Ilu13701 please modify the question title to be more specific. This question comes up in Google results but is largely irrelevant for most asking scenarios around `en_vectors_web_lg`. The title should be something like _What versions of Spacy support en_vectors_web_lg?_

Comment: Also you should accept @Sergii Shcherbak's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naming conventions changed in v3 and the equivalent model is `en_core_web_lg`. It includes vectors and you can install it like this:

```
spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

I would not recommend downgrading to use the old vectors model unless you need to run old code.

If you are concerned about accuracy and have a decent GPU the transformers model, `en_core_web_trf`, is also worth considering, though it doesn't include word vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It [looks like](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases?after=fr_core_news_md-2.0.0a0) `en_vectors_web_lg` is not supported by SpaCy v3.0. The SpaCy v3.0 [installation guide](https://spacy.io/models#quickstart) offers `en_core_web_trf` instead, which is a Transformer-based pipeline.

Comment: can i downgrade my spacy so that it will support vector?

Comment: Yes, you can 
>>> pip3 install -U spacy==2.3.5 
for example. Or any other v2 SpaCy.